# Negative Mass's Effect on Gravitational Time Dilation

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, time-dilation

When I was playing around with the equations for Gravitational Time Dilation, I discovered that when a negative value was plugged in for $M$, the equation gave the exact same answer, and it would never give an imaginary answer if $r$ was positive. Why exactly does this happen?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254858/2451

Comment: *Why exactly does this happen?* GIGO. When you put garbage in, you should not be surprised that you get garbage out.